# PERMISSION_DENIED Firestore Emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security, firebase-tools

The code was work well but suddenly when I try to write on firestore in my emulators I got this error

[image]

**firestore.rules**

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
      allow write: if true;
  }
}
```

I add a plugin same problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in you rules. should be

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

you can learn more about [rules here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started#allow-all)